# ¿Como crear una query que pueda ir aumentando las variables en spring boot?

Tags: angular, postgresql, spring-boot

Muy buenas, tengo mi query de spring boot que es la siguiente

```
@Query("select rh from Producto re inner join CalidadProducto rh on re.id=rh.producto.id where re.calidad.id=?1 and rh.fecha_dia BETWEEN ?2 and ?3")
public List<CalidadProducto > findReservaPorIdproductoFecha(Long id,Date fecha_desde,Date fecha_hasta);
```

Y mi pregunta es:

- ¿Como puedo hacer para que a esta le pueda dar mas parametros?

La idea es tener un arreglo que no tendra siempre la misma cantidad de elementos, por ende la query crecera o disminuira dependiendo del arreglo, por ejemplo si mi arrelgo tubiera 2 datos:

```
@Query("select rh from Producto re inner join CalidadProducto rh on re.id=rh.producto.id where re.calidad.id=?1 or re.calidad.id=?2 and rh.fecha_dia BETWEEN ?3 and ?4")
```

O 3 datos

```
@Query("select rh from Producto re inner join CalidadProducto rh on re.id=rh.producto.id where re.calidad.id=?1 or re.calidad.id=?2 or re.calidad.id=?3 and rh.fecha_dia BETWEEN ?4 and ?5")
```

Todo esto esta hecho con spring boot, angular y postgresql

Answer (score 0):

En este caso utilizamos la misma solución que se utilizaría en SQL y es el operador `IN` para enviar múltiples `Ids`.

Asumiendo que tu query esta correcto la modificación quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
@Query("select rh from Producto re inner join CalidadProducto rh on re.id=rh.producto.id where re.calidad.id IN ?1 and rh.fecha_dia BETWEEN ?2 and ?3")
List<RH> findAllByIdAndFechaDiaBetween(List<Long> ids, Date fechaInicial, Date fechaFinal);
```